# curdate() till rest of the month mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to retrieve data between today and the rest of this month.

```
select * from table where date between curdate() and endmonth();
```

My experience with mysql dates/times is pretty bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has a [`LAST_DAY` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) that returns the last day of the passed month. I'd use that:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND LAST_DAY(CURDATE());
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot about `LAST_DAY()`. Nice, +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with a little trick with `DATE_FORMAT()`

```
select * from table where date between curdate() and DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-31');
```

This way you don't have to deal with complicated `and year(...) = ... and month(...` . It's just nice and easy to write.

Read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND LAST_DAY(CURDATE());
```

Comment: Wrong, you're not considering different years.

Comment: Now you're missing something from the `BETWEEN`

Comment: please @tombom be patient.